# Alternative Proof of Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This is regarding the proof of Heine Borel Theorem for closed intervals on real line as given in Hardy's Pure Mathematics.

**Heine-Borel Theorem**: Let $[a, b]$ be a closed interval with $a < b$ and suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open intervals such that each point of $[a, b]$ lies in some interval from collection $\mathcal{C}$. Then there are a finite number of intervals $I_{1}, I_{2}, \dots, I_{n}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that each point of $[a, b]$ lies in some of these chosen intervals $I_{j}$.

Hardy establishes the existence of a positive number $\delta$ such that any sub-interval $J \subseteq [a, b]$ of length less than $\delta$ lies completely inside some interval $I$ from collection $\mathcal{C}$. The phrase "completely inside" means that if $J = [p, q]$ and $I = (r, s)$ then $r < p < q < s$. Once this $\delta$ is found we make a partition $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ with $||P|| < \delta$ and each subinterval $[x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]$ lies in some $I_{k} \in \mathcal{C}$ and therefore $I_{1}, I_{2}, \dots, I_{n}$ form a finite cover for $[a, b]$.

Hardy gives two proofs for existence of $\delta$. One is easy and based on contradiction. If $\delta$ does not exist then we can find a sequence of sub-intervals $[c_{n}, c_{n} + 2^{-n}] \subseteq [a, b]$ which are not contained in any interval from $\mathcal{C}$. The contradiction comes because points $c_{n}$ have a limit point $c \in [a, b]$ and we can find a neighborhood of $c$ which is contained in some interval from $\mathcal{C}$ and also contains one interval of type $[c_{n}, c_{n} + 2^{-n}]$.

This is quite unlike the many usual proofs of Heine-Borel found in other texts.

> Does this proof offer any advantage over other proofs? Does the $\delta$ obtained in the proof represent some useful quantity?

One direct application could be in proving uniform continuity of a continuous function on closed interval. This $\delta$ found above will fit the one given in definition of uniform continuity. Apart from that I wonder if this has any significant importance.

Comment: The number $\delta$ is the Lebesgue number of $\mathcal C$. The Lebesgue number of a cover is a general concept which extends to metric spaces. On similar lines one can prove that a sequentially compact metric space is compact, a precursor to which is a theorem which states that every open cover of a sequentially compact metric space admits a Lebesgue number.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: To be frank the term "Lebesgue number" is totally new to me. Do you have any reference texts which deal with this concept?

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Google search on "Lebesgue number" does give many references and it appears that after all it does have some significance. I will look study some results from Google search. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: The concept of Lebesgue number can be found in Munkres' *Topology* or Simmons' *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis*. In fact it should be there in any book which discusses compactness in metric spaces.