# ${(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is family set of open intervals

Tags: calculus, limsup-and-liminf

${(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is family set of open intervals for which $\bigcup^{}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)\supset[0,1]$.

Prove that $\exists \epsilon$>0 $\forall x \in [0,1]$ $\exists \lambda_x \in \Lambda$ for which $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset(a_{\lambda_x},b_{\lambda_x}).$

I think that this problem is decided with assuming the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple application of Heine Borel Theorem. Using Heine Borel theorem we can see that a finite number of intervals $(a_\lambda, b_\lambda) $ cover $[0,1]$. Consider the set of all these chosen finite number of values $a_\lambda, b_\lambda $ which lie in $[0,1]$. These points together with $0,1$ form a partition of $[0,1]$. Let $0\in(a_{\lambda_{0}},b_{\lambda_{0}})$ and $1\in(a_{\lambda_{1}},b_{\lambda_{1}})$ and further let $\delta$ be the length of the smallest sub-interval created by the partition of $[0,1]$ described earlier. If we take a positive number $$\epsilon <\min(\delta/2,-a_{\lambda_{0}}/2,(b_{\lambda_{1}}-1)/2)$$ then $\epsilon $ is the desired number (I hope you can see why this is the case).

Answer (score 2):

So as to avoid making the problem trivial, I’ll give a sketch of the proof (at least how I did it), and leave filling in the details to you.

I use the following results:

- if $X$ is a compact set, and $\{O_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is an open cover for $X,$ then there exists a finite $\Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda$ such that $\{O_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0}$ is an open cover for $X.$
- the max/min of finitely many continuous, real-valued functions is again continuous
- if $X$ is compact and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exist $x,y\in X$ such that $$f(x)=\min_{z\in X}f(z)\text{  and  }f(y)=\max_{z\in X}f(z).$$

We start by applying the first of the results above to reduce the open cover to a finite subcover $\Lambda_0$. Now we define for each $x\in[0,1]$ $$\Lambda_0(x):=\{\lambda\in\Lambda_0:a_\lambda<x<b_\lambda\},$$ and the function $$f(x):=\max_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)}\max\{\varepsilon>0:(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)\}.$$ Since each $\Lambda_0(x)$ is finite, we observe that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,1].$ We want to prove that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and then applying the third of the results above, there is some point $x\in[0,1]$ such that $\min_{z\in[0,1]}f(z)=f(x)>0.$ This will complete the proof.

Now to show that $f$ is continuous, we first notice that we can rewrite $f$ as $$f(x)=\max_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)}\min\{|x-a_\lambda|,|x-b_\lambda|\}.$$ Since $y\mapsto\max_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)}\min\{|y-a_\lambda|,|y-b_\lambda|\}$ is continuous using the second result above twice, we are nearly there, but we need to show that if $|x-y|$ is small, then (1) $\Lambda_0(y)\supseteq\Lambda_0(x)$, and (2) if $\Lambda_0(y)\neq\Lambda_0(x),$ that for $\lambda’\in\Lambda_0(y)\setminus\Lambda_0(x),$ $\min\{|y-a_{\lambda’}|,|y-b_{\lambda’}|\}<f(y),$ so that only the $\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)$ contribute to the outer maximization in $f(y)$ (using the second formula). I found the quantity $2\delta:=\min_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)}\min\{|x-a_\lambda|,|x-b_\lambda|\}$ to be helpful for this part.

Note that we do have to consider (2) above, since we may have some $a_\lambda$ or $b_\lambda\in[0,1]$, and if $x=a_{\lambda’}$ (say), then for any positive $\eta,$ there will be $y$ with $|y-x|<\eta,$ but $\Lambda_0(y)\neq\Lambda_0(x).$ As we would expect, however, the $\lambda\in\Lambda_0(x)$ which achieves the maximum in the second formula for $f(x)$ will contain a larger ball around $y$ than $(a_{\lambda’},b_{\lambda’})$ will, when $|x-y|$ is small enough.

Comment: Your approach is essentially a proof of existence of Lebesgue number for the open cover given here. And this is typically used to prove Heine Borel theorem. There is no need to first apply Heine Borel to get a finite subcover. The approach works for infinite cover also. See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1358209/72031 Hardy's second proof is your version with max replaced by supremum without switching to a finite subcover.

Comment: @Paramanand It’s clear upon seeing your answer that I’ve proved more than was necessary to answer the question. Thank you for providing some broader context.

Comment: But I must say that you have discovered a non-obvious proof by yourself (this proof is not available in typical books) so that's commendable. +1

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a Lebesgue number for the cover, then every set of diameter $r$ is contained in some interval $(a_{\lambda},b_{\lambda})$ of the cover. So I think you can take $\epsilon$ to be $r/2.$

Comment: Hmm, do I need a "sub-subscript" of $x$ in the two $\lambda$s here?

Comment: The point to the problem is to show a Lebesgue number exists.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'll insert a proof of existence of Lebesgue number for this set-up soon. [I thought one could just quote the existence... but I see your point.]

Comment: It can be a tricky question, what one is "allowed" to use in proving something. Sometimes pointing out that A is a simple consequence of B makes sense, sometimes it's more like saying A follows from A.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I don't have time in near future to fill in a proof, but I *could* just "cheat" and insert a link. I figured the OP could just google on Lebesgue number anyway.